# Send to child this.props with change of one props

Tags: reactjs, components, parent-child, render

Is there any way how send any props that with come from parent, but with one props changed?

I have some page, where i am rendering `InputList` component. And in this component, i am rendering `InputList` again . So i am sending down `{...this.props}` with one props change - `modal`. But when i send down `<InputList modal={true} {this.props}/>`. The `modal` value is taking from `...this.props`. so the value is `false` instead of `true`, any tips?

Sure, there is a possibility of sending all props individually but i have a lot of props, so i want use `this.props`.. Or i can use something like `const { modal, ...others} = this.props`, but there are more props, that with i am using so i have `const { modal,...,...,...,...,...} = this.props`

```
    class Page extends Component{
       render(){
         return(
              <InputList modal={false} list={...} valueA={..} valueB={..} 
                    firstTitle={..} secondTitle={..} />
         )
       }
    }

    class InputList extends Component{
       render(){
          const {modal,list,valueA,valueB,firstTitle,secondTitle} = this.props;
            ....
         return(
            ....
              <InputList modal={true} {...this.props} />
         )
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
class InputList extends Component {
  render(){
    const passProps = Object.assign({}, this.props, {modal: true})
    return(
      ....
      <InputList {...passProps} />
    )
}
```